# Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: android, gradle

Перешел на Ubuntu и решил поставить Android Studio. Решил для теста собрать проект и получил ошибку:

```
Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_5q5nq7m97ifriua75ndy8hd4v$_run_closure3@62f16c93] on root project 'MyApplication2' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:/home/jeka/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

build.gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    dexOptions {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}
dependencies {
}
```

Никогда с таким ранее не стыкался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы забыли плагин задействовать

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
```